# How can I include a navigation.css and .html in all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed and seperate navigation and footer file (html, css) and I want to know how to include them in all pages without inserting all codes in all page. I mean how can I link them in all other pages.(Just with HTML,CSS and JS)

Answer (score 1):

You could load the html file into an element using jquery.

By specifying a relative path

```
$("#footer").load("./footer.html");
```

or loading it from a url:

```
$("#footer").load("http://yoursite.com/footer.html");
```